# Previous question button in JavaScript and saving users answers

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a JavaScript quiz and I need the user to be able to go to the previous question to see or change his/her answer . The next button works with me but I have a problem with the previous button . what I also need is when the user goes back, the original answer should be saved. here is my code. I also put it on [codepen](https://codepen.io/f6m7/pen/gOLQBbm)

```js
const questionNumber = document.querySelector(".question_number");
const questionText = document.querySelector(".question_text");
const optionContainer = document.querySelector(".option_container");
const answerIndecatorContainer = document.querySelector(".answer_indicator");
const homeBox = document.querySelector(".home_box");
const quizBox = document.querySelector(".quiz_box");
const resultBox = document.querySelector(".result_box");
const registerBox = document.querySelector(".register_box");
const timeBox = document.querySelector("time_box");

let questionCounter = 0;
let currentQuestion;
let availableQuestions = [];
let availableOptions = [];
let correctAnswers = 0;
let attempt = 0;

//push the question into availableQuestions array
function setAvailableQuestions(){
    const totalQuestion = quiz.length;
    for (let i=0; i<totalQuestion; i++){
        availableQuestions.push(quiz[i])
    }
}

// set question number and question options
function getNewQuestions(){
    //set question number
    questionNumber.innerHTML = "Question " + (questionCounter +1) + " of " + quiz.length;
    // set question text
    //get random questions
    const questionIndex = availableQuestions[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length)]
    currentQuestion = questionIndex;
    questionText.innerHTML = currentQuestion.q;
    //get the position of 'questionIndex' from the availableQuestions array
    const index1 = availableQuestions.indexOf(questionIndex);
    // remove the questionIndex from the availableQuestions array, so that the question does not repeat
    availableQuestions.splice(index1,1);
    //console.log(questionIndex)
    //console.log(availableQuestions)


    //set options
    //get the length of options
   const optionLen =  currentQuestion.options.length
   //push options into availableOptions array
   for (let i=0; i<optionLen; i++){
        availableOptions.push(i)
   }
    optionContainer.innerHTML = '';
   let animationDelay = 0.15;
   //create options in html
   for(let i=0; i<optionLen; i++){
        //random options
        const optionIndex = availableOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableOptions.length)];
        //get the position of optionIndex from the availableOptions
        const index2 = availableOptions.indexOf(optionIndex);
        //remove the optionIndex from availableOptions
        availableOptions.splice(index2,1);
        const option = document.createElement("div");
        option.innerHTML = currentQuestion.options[optionIndex];
        option.id = optionIndex;
        option.style.animationDelay= animationDelay + 's';
        animationDelay = animationDelay + 0.15;
        option.className = "option";
        optionContainer.appendChild(option)
        option.setAttribute("onclick", "getResult(this)");
   }
    questionCounter++
}
//get result of current attempt
function getResult(element){
    const id = parseInt(element.id);
    //get the answer by compairing the id of the options
    if (id === currentQuestion.answer){
        //set the green color to the correct option
        element.classList.add("correct");
        //add color to indector if answer is correct
        updateAnswerIndecator("correct");
        correctAnswers++;

    }else{
        //set the red color to the incorrect option
        element.classList.add("wrong");
        //add color to indector if answer is wrong
        updateAnswerIndecator("wrong");
    }
    attempt++;
    //unclickableOptions();
}

/*make all options unclickable once the user select
function unclickableOptions(){
    const optionLen = optionContainer.children.length;
    for(let i=0 ; i<optionLen ; i++){
        optionContainer.children[i].classList.add("aready-answered");
    }
}*/

function answerIndecator(){
    answerIndecatorContainer.innerHTML = '';
    const totalQuestion = quiz.length;
    for (let i=0 ; i<totalQuestion ; i++){
        const indecator = document.createElement("div");
        answerIndecatorContainer.appendChild(indecator);
    }
} function updateAnswerIndecator(markType){
    answerIndecatorContainer.children[questionCounter-1].classList.add(markType);
}

function next(){
    if (questionCounter === quiz.length){

        quizOver();
    }else{
        getNewQuestions();
    }
//

}

//Previous button
/*function previous(){
    if (questionCounter == 0) {
       questionCounter = quiz.length - 1;
     } // reset question
     else {
       questionCounter--;
     }
}*/
//
function quizOver(){
    //when the quiz is over, the  timer stops
//window.clearInterval(update);
clearInterval(countdownTimer);
  upgradeTime = "-";
    //show the registrer box
    registerBox.classList.remove("hide");
    //hide quiz box
    quizBox.classList.add("hide");

}

function register(){
    //show the result box
    resultBox.classList.remove("hide");
    //
    registerBox.classList.add("hide");
    quizResult();
}

//get the quiz result
function quizResult(){
    resultBox.querySelector(".total_question").innerHTML = quiz.length;
    resultBox.querySelector(".total_attempt").innerHTML = attempt;
    resultBox.querySelector(".total_correct").innerHTML = correctAnswers;
    resultBox.querySelector(".total_wrong").innerHTML = attempt - correctAnswers;
    const persentage = (correctAnswers/quiz.length)*100;
    resultBox.querySelector(".persentage").innerHTML = persentage.toFixed(2) + "%";
    resultBox.querySelector(".total_score").innerHTML = correctAnswers + " / " + quiz.length;
}

function resetQuiz(){
     questionCounter = 0;
     correctAnswers = 0;
     attempt = 0;

}

function tryAgainQuiz(){
    //hide the resultBox
    resultBox.classList.add("hide");
    //show the quizBox
    quizBox.classList.remove("hide");

    resetQuiz();
    startQuiz();
}

function goToHome(){
    //hide the result box
    resultBox.classList.add("hide");
    //show home box
    homeBox.classList.remove("hide");

    resetQuiz();
}
//###STARTING POINT###

function startQuiz() {
    //start timer
    upgradeTime = 20;
    seconds = upgradeTime;
    //hide home Box
    homeBox.classList.add("hide");
    //show the quiz box
    quizBox.classList.remove("hide");
    //first we set all questions in availableQuestions array
    setAvailableQuestions();
    //second we will call the getNewQuestions() funcrion
    getNewQuestions();
    //to create indecator of answers
    answerIndecator();

}
function timer() {
var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
function pad(n) {
return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
}
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "الوقت المتبقي :" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(remainingSeconds);
if (seconds == 0) {
clearInterval(countdownTimer);
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "انتهى الوقت";
quizBox.classList.add("hide");
registerBox.classList.remove("hide");

//show the result box
/*resultBox.classList.remove("hide");
quizResult();*/

} else {
seconds--;
}
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
window.onload = function (){
    homeBox.querySelector(".total_question").innerHTML = quiz.length;
}


//array of objects
const quiz = [
    {
        q:' أوجد قيمة: \(\left( {3 + \sqrt 3 } \right) - \sqrt 3  + 18\) ',
        options:['٨٤','\(81 + \sqrt 6 \)','٧٨','٧٩'],
        answer:0
    },
    {
        q:' HOW',
        options:['٣٤,١ دقيقة ','٣,١٤ دقيقة ','٣١٤ دقيقة','٣٤١ دقيقة '],
        answer:0
    },
    {
        q:'ا قيمة  \(\frac{{{9^4} - {9^6}}}{{{9^2} - {9^3}}}\) ',
        options:['800','810','9','\({9^3}\)'],
        answer:0
    },
    {
        q:'ذا كانت مساحة الدائرة الصغيرة = 16 ط فإن محيط المنطقة المظللة = ',
        options:['64 ط','4ط','8ط','24'],
        answer:3
    },
    {
        q:'حتاج ارض زراعية 15 يوم لينمو فيها  \(1.2 + {10^8}\) من لا شيء فكم تحتاج لينمو فيها  \(4.0 + {10^8}\) من لا شيء',
        options:['18','60','13','45'],
        answer:1
    },
    {
        q:'حتاج ارض زراعية 15 يوم لينمو فيها  \(1.2 + {10^8}\) من لا شيء فكم تحتاج لينمو فيها  \(4.0 + {10^8}\) من لا شيء',
        options:['18','60','13','45'],
        answer:1
    }
]
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,700&display=swap');
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #009688;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    outline:none;
}

.custom_box{
    max-width: 700px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 49px auto;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 10PX;
    animation: fadeInRight 1s ease;
}
@keyframes fadeInRight{
    0%{
        transform: translateX(40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
.custom_box::before,
.custom_box::after{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.custom_box.hide{
    display: none;
}

.home_box h3{
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:500;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 25px; 
}

.home_box p{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height:22px;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:400;
}

.home_box p span{
    font-weight: 500;
}

.home_box .btn{
    margin-top: 20px; 
}

.btn{
    padding: 15px 45px;
    background-color: #009688;
    color: #ffffff;
    border:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}

.quiz_box .question_number,
.quiz_box .question_text,
.quiz_box .option_container,
.quiz_box .next_question_btn,
.quiz_box .answer_indicator{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.quiz_box .question_number{
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#009688;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.quiz_box .question_text{
    font-size: 22px;
    color:#000000;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0; 
}


.quiz_box .option_container .option{
    background-color: #cccccc;
    padding:13px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease forwards;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.quiz_box .option_container .option.aready-answered{
    pointer-events: none;
}
@keyframes fadeIn{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
.quiz_box .option_container .option.correct::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: -1;
    animation: slideInLift .5s ease forwards
}
@keyframes slideInLift{
    0%{
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
.quiz_box .option_container .option.correct{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.quiz_box .btn{
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.quiz_box .answer_indicator{
    border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;

}

.quiz_box .answer_indicator div{
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right:3px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.quiz_box .answer_indicator div.correct{
    background-color: green;
}
.quiz_box .answer_indicator div.wrong{
    background-color: red;
}
.result_box{
    text-align: center;
}

.result_box.hide{
    display: none;
}

.result_box h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 42px;
    color: #009688;
}
.result_box table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin:30px 0;
}
.result_box table td{
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000000;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.result_box .btn{
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="random_style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="home_box custom_box">
    <h3>هذا الاختبار يحتوي على ٢٥ سؤال بمدة ٢٥ دقيقة</h3>
    <p>عدد الأسئلة: <span class="total_question"></span></p>
    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="startQuiz()">ابدأ الاختبار </button>
   </div>

            <div class="time_box custom_box ">
            <span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
                      <!-- <text>الوقت المتبقي: <text id="time001">1200</text></text><br/>-->
            </div>
 <div class="quiz_box custom_box hide">
        <div class="question_number">

        </div>
        <div class="question_text">

        </div>
        <div class="option_container">

        </div>
        <div class="next_question_btn">
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="next()">التالي</button>
        <!--    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="previous()">السابق</button>-->


        </div>
        <div class="answer_indicator">

        </div>
 </div>
 <div class="register_box custom_box hide" style="direction: rtl;">
    <form >
        <p>الرجاء ادخال بياناتك للحصول على نتيجة اختبارك </p><br>

        <label for="uname">اسمك الكامل <br></label>
        <input type="text"  class="w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" placeholder="ادخل اسمك الكامل " name="uname" required><br>

   <label for="email">الايميل <br></label>
   <input type="email"  class="w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" placeholder="ادخل اسمك الكامل " name="email" required><br>

   <label for="phone">رقم الجوال (اختياري )<br></label>
   <input type="number"  class="w3-input w3-border w3-round-large" placeholder="ادخل رقم الجوال " name="phone"><br>
       <button type="button" value="submit" onclick="register()"class="btn">تسجيل </button>

    </form >
 </div>

 <div class="result_box custom_box hide">
        <h1>النتيجة</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> total questions</td>
                <td><span class="total_question"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>attempt</td>
                <td><span class="total_attempt"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>correct</td>
                <td><span class="total_correct"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>wrong</td>
                <td><span class="total_wrong"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>persentage</td>
                <td><span class="persentage"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>your total score</td>
                <td><span class="total_score"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="tryAgainQuiz()">try again</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="goToHome()">go to home</button>
 </div>

<script src="quistion.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should possibly consider using `sessionStorage` to maintain a record of question and answer so you can lookup previous values

Comment: two options to do that .
1. sessionStorage
2. you can show hide divs for every question & store clicked answers in array, like myArray.push("selcted_answer")

Comment: on option click, send option Id in array. and update the localstorage.

Comment: Thanks, the sessionStorage will be useful to save answers but the main problem is how to go tp the previous question ?